# Why does ShowDialog select text in my TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a very simple error popup I'm trying to make. When I call ShowDialog, all the text in the textbox gets selected. It looks silly. When I break right before ShowDialog, no text is selected. After the call to ShowDialog, all the text is selected without any user interaction.

```
    static void ShowError(string error)
    {
        var form = new Form
        {
            Text = "Unexpected Error",
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600),
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent,
            ShowIcon = false,
            MinimizeBox = false,
            MaximizeBox = false
        };

        var textBox = new TextBox
        {
            Text = error,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Multiline = true,
            ReadOnly = true,
        };

        form.Controls.Add(textBox);
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `SelectionStart=0, SelectionLength = 0` or `Enabled = false` to your textBox creation code

Comment: Already tried modifying selection to no avail. Like I said, before ShowDialog, there is no selection, i.e. SelectedText == "", SelectionStart == 0, and SelectionLength == 0. Enabled = false works, but it makes the text gray and I want the user to be able to copy/paste the error.

Comment: @MattChambers I tried your code with adding `SelectionStart=0, SelectionLength = 0` and it works

Comment: Bah! This must be a bug. It works just with SelectionStart=0; SelectionLength=0 is irrelevant. But I reconfirmed that even without SelectionStart=0, SelectionStart==0 before the call to ShowDialog!

Comment: Setting the TabStop to false on all my text boxes in the modal form works well.  That was suggested by Steve below, and it seems the best option to me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you set TabStop=false; the control will be deselected. However, ReadOnly means that your user could always select text manually.

FROM MSDN - `. With the property set to true, users can still scroll and highlight text in a text box without allowing changes.`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting SelectionStart explicitly, though I'm not sure why this is necessary:

```
static void ShowError(string error)
{
    var form = new Form
    {
        Text = "Unexpected Error",
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600),
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent,
        ShowIcon = false,
        MinimizeBox = false,
        MaximizeBox = false
    };

    form.SuspendLayout();
    var textBox = new TextBox
    {
        Text = error,
        Name = "textBox1",
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Multiline = true,
        ReadOnly = true,
        SelectionStart = 0, // or = error.Length if you prefer
    };

    form.Controls.Add(textBox);
    form.ResumeLayout();
    form.PerformLayout();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```